# Facebook returns 404 error on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-status-code-404

We have a website, but Facebook does not like our website.. All users can visit it, Google has no problems with it, Google Webmaster tools displays the correct website, but the Facebook Graphs API and the debug tool are return a 404 error.

The website it's about:
http://www.gekvanfietsen.nl/ervaringen/11,ervaringen_met_de_santos_travelmaster_28_alu.html

Here are some screenshots of the response code in Chrome and from the Facebook Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gekvanfietsen.nl%2Fervaringen%2F11%2Cervaringen_met_de_santos_travelmaster_28_alu.html

[image: Facebook error]

[image: Website state]

Hoping someone could help me, we've tried everything we could think of.. Double checking .htaccess, checking for any 404 headers and whatsoever.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your rewrite engine config in .htaccess. If I test http://www.gekvanfietsen.nl/webshop/index.php in facebook object debugger, it returned http 206, while browsers were redirected to 404.html

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, you refer to the FB API again. Use this [JavaScript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) that is easy and most browsers supports it.

If you are just looking for a Like button with a count, you are looking in wrong place.

Refer to this Social Plugin [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), fill out the form and choose Iframe code/javascript code,(as FBML is not supported in all browsers). Use ready/generated code and you are ready to go.

It will give you something like this example:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fplugins%2Flike&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Please reply any question...

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to W3TC settings:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-facebook-404-error-on-debugging